VS Code not listing custom CSS properties correctly when using var() more than once
A very odd problem. In VS Code I have 2 .css files one with just a :root{} section that has 3 custom properties in it. In the other file I have a reference to 2 elements with the background-color set. When I comment one element out, I can see all 3 of the custom properties in the list of suggestions, but as soon as I uncomment the 2nd element I can only see 1 property in the list of suggestions. code below... it seems to be related to using the var() function ... rather than to the elements. If I only have 1 element, say the #header, then add a second line, say color: var(--???); I get the same behavior. I have rebooted, restarted, made a new project, etc. There are no extensions running and only one that is installed is LiveServer (but disabled).  Version info ...
Version: 1.90.0 (user setup)
Commit: 89de5a8d4d6205e5b11647eb6a74844ca23d2573
Date: 2024-06-04T19:33:54.889Z
Electron: 29.4.0
ElectronBuildId: 9593362
app-basics.css:
:root {

    --color-0: red;
    --color-1: green;
    --color-2: blue;

}

header-footer.css:
 #header {
     background-color: var(--color-1);
 }


 /* #dummy {
     background-color: var(--color-1);
 } */

Adding a second element like #dummy should have no effect on the custom properties that I can see. I have tried rebooting, restarting, making a new project, renaming the custom properties, re-ordering the properties, checking spelling and syntax. VS code shows no errors or problems with the files. I am stumped on this one.

I personally cannot repro. but since you've tried all the things you've tried, it smells like possible bug to me. I'd suggest you raise an issue ticket with all the details you've provided here. If you do, please add a link here to your issue ticket.

Added a bug issue - # https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/214871

An issue ticket was raised at [css] look for variables in all open documents #214871, and one of the maintainers, Martin Aeschlimann gave an explanation of why this happens:

What's happening is that when the code completion is invoked the first time, textual proposals are shown as the CSS language server has no proposals. Once there's a color name in the file, the CSS language server shows that color. The textual proposals don't show anymore

textual proposals uses the contents of all open editors
the css extension only uses the current document
the textual proposals are considered a 'fallback' is there's no language server providing any results.


I suggest giving that issue ticket a thumbs up and patiently waiting for it to be addressed (or helping implement a solution).
